# How binding my ListBox correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, listbox, windows-phone

My Windows Phone app, have a ListBox populated from a collection `produtos`. This collection received values from a JSON.

In my ListBox, I "binding" all values from JSON (quantidade, descricao, valor_preco_a, codigo), and a another value (unidade) that it should be `produtos.quantidade * produtos.valor_preco_a`.

My ListBox:

```
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Consulta" Name="consultaCartao">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListBox Name="List2" ItemsSource="{Binding produtosCartao}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,182,-66,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="Auto">
                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE8FF00" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                </StackPanel.Background>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding descricao}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="20,5,12,0">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding quantidade}" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding unidade}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding valor, ConverterCulture=pt-BR, StringFormat=C2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="300,-30,12,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I trying with this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<produtos> produtosCartao { get; set; }

    public class produtos
    {

        public double quantidade { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public double valor_preco_a { get; set; }
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string unidade { get; set; }
        public double valor { get; set; }
    }

void webClient_DownloadStringCompletedProdutos(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      produtos produto = new produtos();
      produto.valor = produto.valor_preco_a * produto.quantidade;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use data binding en XAML, you have to set your DataContext property in your listbox.

DataContext property is an object where the xaml engine looks in order to find values that are binded.

You should take a look to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: the data are being binding normally. But the `produtos.value` must be a junction of two other values. So, in my code, i have to do `produto.valor = produto.valor_preco_a * produto.quantidade`.

Comment: Yes I understood, but the junction sould not be a problem for the binding. So what is your problem? The value is not displayed?

Comment: The value displayed is 0,00. But I know that the values are not 0.

Comment: Ok so try setting the DataContext like I said earlier. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Nice, the problem it was the DataContext. It works fine for me now. Thank you bro